# Custom Ribbon Button is not appearing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have created an elements.xml file to make a ribbon control for my test site but the control is not getting displayed on the ribbon. I am trying to look on a document library "shared documents" and below is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Id="CustomRibbonControlTest1"
        Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children"
        RegistrationId="101"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Title="CustomRibbonControlTest1Title"
        Sequence="60"
        >

        <CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children">
                    <Button
                        Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls.CustomCommandButton1_CustomRibbonControlTest1"
                        Command="JSAlert"
                        CommandType="General"
                        LabelText="Click Me To Test"
                        Sequence="60"
                        />

                </CommandUIDefinition>

            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
                <CommandUIHandler Command="JSAlert"
                                  CommandAction="javascript:alert('hello world!');">

                </CommandUIHandler>
            </CommandUIHandlers>
        </CommandUIExtension>

    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I was working on a sandboxed solution and it was not deploying my code to the site. Dont know! why ? but when I created a new project with farm solution and pasted the same code, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You couldd try changing your `CustomAction[Location]` into `Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"`. Example:

```
<CustomAction Id="YourRibbonButton" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" Title="Your Button">
```

And perhaps try a lower `Sequence`, and also try removing the `Registration*` just to test.

Comment: Still not working, below is the changed code as per your suggestion.

  <CustomAction
         Id="CustomRibbonControlTest1"
         Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
        
         Title="CustomRibbonControlTest1Title"
        
        >